# OAuth 1.0 signing code written in C#

Tags: dropbox-api

Right now I am using some open source C# library to sign my URL using OAuth 1.0. I am signing it in order to download a file from Dropbox. It works on all the cases, except when the file has the "(" character in it. When it has that character, I am getting the following error:

```
{"error": "Host: rpc.dropbox.com:443, FE: None, X-Dropbox-RequestId: None, 
  X-Dropbox-App-Error: None, Invalid or missing signature"}
```

I am thinking it is due to the OAuth authentication code I am using. Any good library out there ? Also, I need the library to work on .Net 2.0. Anything higher than that won't work for me. I know it sucks, but that's my limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a file name encoding issue.  I got the same error when the file name had a space in it. I solved the problem by replacing the space with %20.  You could try replacing the ( char with %28.

Comment: Hi Mozgras. I am actually appending %28 for all reserved characters. Here are the unreserved characters that do not need encoding in the code: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~". So "(", as well as ")" fall into the reserved category, and are being correctly encoding. For some reason Dropbox doesn't like it

Comment: I was over-thinking. You are right. It does need to be escaped. I was escaping it but only during signature generation, not within the file name itself.
Incorrect request: https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/123(.docx?oauth_consumer_key={therestoftheurl}. Replace "(" with "%28" and it will work !

Comment: To get all those characters an escape function is helpful. I used php's rawurlencode on the file name itself. In c# I think the function is HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode.